# Сортировка чисел по возрастанию (без сортировки)

Tags: java

Вводится массив чисел с клавиатуры, нужно вывести их отсортированными по возрастанию, то есть первым выводится наименьшее число. Если есть одинаковые числа, то они тоже выводятся все. Сортировку нужно написать самостоятельно, а не использовать встроенные методы.

Вопрос: можно ли использовать приведённый ниже код или он будет слишком "ресурсоёмким" и выгоднее использовать "пузырьковую" сортировку? Что можно в нём улучшить?

Я начинающий, поэтому возможны "ляпы")) Спасибо.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int n = 100; //задание количества вводимых чисел
    int max = 100000000; // максимальное значение вводимых чисел
    int[] negative = new int[max]; //создание массива для отрицательных чисел заданного размера с нулями во всех ячейках
    int[] positive = new int[max]; //аналогично создан положительный массив

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int z = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        if (z < 0) negative[-z]++; //если введённое число отрицательное, то увеличиваем нужную ячейку отрицательного массива на 1  
        else positive[z]++; //если положительное или ноль, то аналогично записываем его в положительный массив
    }

    for (int i = max-1; i > 0; i--) //вывод на печать чисел из отрицательного массива, если было несколько одинаковых, то выводим их тоже все 
        while (negative[i] > 0) { //если ячейка больше нуля, то хотя бы одно число с таким номером было введено
            System.out.println("-" + i); //приписываем впереди минус, так как номера ячеек массива отрицательными быть не могут 
            negative[i]--;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) //аналогично вывод на печать положительного массива
        while (positive[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
            positive[i]--;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: по-моему, для отрицательных чисел должно быть for (int i = max; i > 0; i--)

Comment: имхо, тут место очереди с приоритетами, и код был бы проще, и памяти бы съело меньше.

Comment: ну или для 100 элементов можно хоть пузырек, хоть вставки - слишком маленькое количество чисел, чтобы были какие то отличия от более сложных сортировок

Comment: ну и если человек введет `100000000` - максимальное значение, то всё у вас упадет

Comment: Да, вывод отрицательных чисел исправил. А вот интересно, как очистить оперативную память Windows 7 после запуска этой программы?  IDEA  закрывал, но оперативка не освободилась...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сортировка подсчётом. Для небольших массивов она избыточна, но если диапазон невелик и в качестве тренировки - почему бы и нет...

Только вот отрицательные числа надо с конца выводить.

И лучше запоминать максимумы, чтобы не обегать все массивы.

А ещё лучше сначала выявить максимум и минимум, чтобы завести массивы нужного размера.

На размерах массивов, которые реально можно ввести с клавиатуры, простые сортировки будут работать быстрее и не будут использовать дополнительную память.

Добавлю, что сортировка пузырьком практического смысла, кроме учебного, не имеет. Из простых лучше освойте сортировку вставками и сортировку выбором (в реализации последней трудно ошибиться, даже если делать на скорую руку)

Comment: Я рассматривал вариант с минимумом и максимумом, но тогда нужно будет создавать начальный несортированный массив вводимых чисел, а потом его распределять в два сортированных массива. Мне показалось, что это будет дольше чем сразу записывать числа в правильные ячейки....

Comment: Сравните, сколько времени нужно на обход миллиарда ячеек

Answer (score 0):

Вот сортировка вставками (как уже ответил **MBo** она проще):

```
    int[] arr = {-10,-10,-9,99,0,89, 11,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-100,8,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,-3,-2,-10};


    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[i] < arr[--j]) {
            if (j == 0 || arr[i] >= arr[j - 1]) {
                int x = arr[i];
                for (int k = i; k > j; k--)
                    arr[k] = arr[k - 1];
                arr[j] = x;
            }
        }
    }
```

//вывод в консоль:

```
    for (int x : arr)
        System.out.print(x + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
   import java.util.*;

   public class Sorter {
          public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 5; // сколько цифр будет в массиве
    int count = 0; // Вот эту переменную можно и не создавать
    int id = 1;

    int[] arrName = new int[number];

    TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) { // цикл будет идти пока пользователь не заполнит все числа в массиве
        System.out.printf("Введите число %d:\n", id++);

        arrName[count] = scanner.nextInt(); // А здесь вместо 'arrName[count]' просто указать 0 именно вместо count

        System.out.println();

        treeSet.add(arrName[count]); // И тут 0
    }

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(treeSet);

    Collections.reverse(list); // Если хотите чтоб наибольшее число было внизу, а наименьшее было сверху то удалите эту строку и все

    for (Integer integer : list) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

}

Вместо "int number = 5;" Можно сделать например так чтоб пользователь мог сам указать свою длину массива:

```
System.out.println("Введите длину массива:");

number = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println();

int[] name = new int[number];

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
// Тот код //
}
```

Очень просто и коротко.